# On the topology of a set

Tags: general-topology

Let us consider the set $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and define the standard topology on it. That can be visualized as the $2$-D Euclidean plane. Now if I consider a set of all points that lie inside and on the boundary of a square in the plane and name that set $M$ and then take the inherited topology on the set $M$ name it $O$, does that topology $O$ contains a subset of $M$ that has the boundary points of $M$?

Comment: $M$ itself is in the topology of $O$

Comment: Are you asking if $O$ contains a subset of $M$ which contains _only_ the boundary points of $M$?

Comment: For a set to be in a standard topology, it has to have a soft ball defined on every point in the set. $M$ has points lying on the boundary of the square also. For those boundary points we cant define a soft ball, right? So how is $M$ itself in the topology?

Comment: It looks like you have some mis-understandings of the inherited topology on $M$, which you have named $O$. By definition, a subset $A \subset M$ is an element of $O$ if and only if there exists an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that $A=M\cap U$. So, for example, $M$ is an element of $O$ because $M=M\cap (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.